# How to raise desktops without clicking on "Activities"

Tags: mouse, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I've searched and not found this question.  Long time Ubuntu user, and the last several years a Gnubuntu user (and happy about the switch to Gnome).  HOWEVER, how in the world do I get Activities to raise the desktops by just sending my mouse pointer to the upper left hand corner of the screen (like I used to do in Gnubuntu)?  Having to click on "Activities" to do this is really slowing me down.

I know, first world problems, but this is driving me batty.

Thanks.

Brand new Ubuntu 18.04 install, not an upgrade over 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can answer my own question.  Gnome tweak tool's Top Bar settings:  turn on Activities Overview Hot Corner.

Finally.

I'm sure I'm the only one jangled by this, but hopefully it will help someone.